# how can i search in django for multiple values like the ( werkstoffbezeichnung and the werkstoffnummer )

Tags: python, django

This cod I made only works for one values, when I try to add other one it stops working.
how can i fix it?

```
def search_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST.get('searched')
        posts = Post.objects.filter(werkstoffnummer=searched)
        posts = Post.objects.filter(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched)
        
        
        
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {'searched': searched, 'posts': posts})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {})
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: no error comes up, just not working when i search for something's i posted already

Comment: How are your models defined? (please update first post with related code)

Comment: you are overwriting `posts` in second call `posts = Post.objects.filter(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched)` and hence you see this behavior

Comment: Try debugging it. Search for debugging python code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching that way, `posts` will be set to the last `QuerySet` you define.

You can work with `Q` objects to make a `QuerySet` that searches for both fields:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def search_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        searched = request.POST.get('searched')
        posts = Post.objects.filter(
            Q(werkstoffnummer=searched) | Q(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched)
        )
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {'searched': searched, 'posts': posts})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behavior is `posts` is overwritten in the call `posts = Post.objects.filter(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched)` and hence you see only 1 result. Here is one of the approach:

```
def search_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST.get('searched')
        posts = Post.objects.filter(werkstoffnummer=searched) | Post.objects.filter(werkstoffbezeichnung=searched)
   
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {'searched': searched, 'posts': posts})
    else:
        return render(request, 'Blog/search_post.html', {})
```

You can refer to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#operators-that-return-new-querysets) for more details.